# disjoint pattern database for 15 puzzle

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I have some questions.
1.How to create disjoint pattern data bases for 15 puzzle?
2.What does pattern database (5-5-5) or (6-3-2) mean?

Comment: **1)** You must specify a target pattern and then construct the set of all patterns that can be obtained from the target pattern by permutation. Which part is giving you trouble? **2)** I have no idea; where do `(5-5-5)` and `(6-3-2)` come from?

Comment: Please give an example for section 1.

Comment: An example of a target pattern? Or of permutation? Or of a set of patterns obtainable by permutation?

Comment: An example for all of these. In fact i don't understand how to specify a target pattern. Is target pattern a random pattern or is goal?

Comment: I wrote [a paper](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/index/index/docId/6558) on this subject. Maybe it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to do too much at once. Consider this state of the puzzle:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5 10  6  8
 9  7  _ 12
13 14 11 15
```

(where `_` is the empty space). A **permutation** (in this context) is an exchange of the empty space with a neighboring tile:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5 10  6  8
 9  7 12  _
13 14 11 15
```

A **pattern** is a partial specification of a state, in which (in this context) some tiles may be unspecified, like this:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  *  *  *
 9  *  *  *
13  *  *  _
```

This particular pattern looks like a **target pattern**, which is to say a partial specification of the goal state. The **pattern database** of this pattern is the set of all patterns that can be obtained from this pattern by permutation, with the corresponding minimum number of moves needed to reach that state from this one. Here is another target pattern:

```
 *  *  *  *
 *  6  7  8
 * 10 11 12
 * 14 15  _
```

Notice that these two target patterns are **disjoint** (they have no tiles in common), so their pattern databases are called **disjoint pattern databases**.

Does that help?

Comment: while reading AI:AMA I came across pattern databases. Could you please suggest any further materials which could help me to understand more about this?

Comment: @senseiwu: I don't think I'd ever heard of them before I saw this question. I probably looked them up in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

That mean first we must generate all posible permutation from

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  *  *  *
 9  *  *  *
 13  *  * _
```

for example it will be

```
 1  *  3  4           
 5  2  *  *
 9  *  *  *
 13  *  * _ 

 1  2  3  *
 5  *  *  4
 9  *  *  *
 13  *  * _
```

and then from this permutation run BFS and try to reach goal state ?

How to generate all this permutation from this numbers 1,2,3,4,5,9,13 some pseudocode ?